# Lazy property inside struct

Tags: swift, swift2

I was trying to implement a simple lazy object type:

```
struct LazyType<T> {
    typealias Instantiator = () -> T

    private let instantiator: Instantiator
    private lazy var object: T = {
        return self.instantiator()
    }()

    init(_ instantiator: Instantiator) {
        self.instantiator = instantiator
    }

    var lazyObject: T {
        mutating get {
            return object
        }
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    let urlPath: String

    init(urlPath: String) {
        self.urlPath = urlPath
    }
}

private var someLazyVar = LazyType<SomeClass>() {
    let myGithubRepositoryUrl = "someone.github.io"

    print(myGithubRepositoryUrl)

    return SomeClass(urlPath: myGithubRepositoryUrl)
}

private let someClassVar = someLazyVar.lazyObject
```

and got some strange compile-time error:

> Command failed to signal: Abort trap: 6

... but it looks more like a runtime error.

Commenting out the last line resolves the issue.

Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Comment: Which Xcode? Does work for me with _Version 7.0 beta 4 (7A165t)_. More context? Code around? Whole Swift file? This looks like compiler issue.

Comment: Version 7.0 beta (7A121l)

Comment: Then update your Xcode to _Version 7.0 beta 4 (7A165t)_. It's beta, lot of fixes in new betas and you should always check if your problem is still valid with the latest beta release.

Comment: Thanks! Doing it right now (downloading the latest beta release). If it will compile I will close this thread.

Comment: I had an abort trap 6 that got fixed by upgrading as well. It was giving this error in about a dozen different situations that were fixed by the later beta.

Comment: Yep, that's worked. Thanks folks!